# Batch Loop through command result (command in a different folder)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to Loop through results of a command with FOR /F.

The command to actually run - C:\Program Files\my folder\command.exe

%installdir% is C:\Program Files\my folder\

The code I run is -

```
FOR /F "delims=, tokens=1,2" %%c in (results.txt) DO (
  if %%d EQU [something] (
    FOR /F "delims=: skip=2" %%e in ('%installdir%command.exe /checkstatus Client %%c') do (
      echo %%e %%f
    )
  )
)
```

I'm guessing this is not running correctly because I need to use usebackq in some fashion, but I haven't managed to do so.
Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=: skip=2" %%e in ('"%installdir%command.exe" /checkstatus ....
                                  ^         quotes        ^
```

If your command includes spaces, you need to quote it.

The problem with this is that sametimes the `cmd` instance that is started to handle the command to execute removes some double quotes (the quotes we added) and at the end we get a new error (see `cmd /?` for more information)

To solve it, you will need to add ... more quotes.

```
FOR /F "delims=: skip=2" %%e in ('""%installdir%command.exe" /checkstatus ... "') do ....
        quoted executable          ^.......................^ 
        quoted full command       ^...........................................^
```

You will need `usebackq` when

- You run a command that needs single quotes in it, so you use backquotes to enclose the command
- You are reading a file and needs to use double quotes because it includes spaces/special chars. A double quoted string is handled as a direct string to process and need `usebackq` to indicate that it is a file name.

You can see both cases indicated if you execute `for /?`

Comment: Result in this way is - 
`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: The Command which will need to run is - 

**C:\Program Files\My Folder\command.exe /checkstatus Client machineFQDN**  

After checking the above solution, the result is that it grabs - **C:\Program**   
And not the rest of the command.

Comment: Here is the result after changing to the new updated answer -  **'"C:\Program Files\my folder\command.exe"' is
not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: @morrtz, i can only get your indicated behaviour when the called executable does not exist or can not be started.

Comment: You are right, was missing a folder in the path.
Thanks for all the help, issue solved :)